# Bootstrap Mobile Navigation Slide in from Right

Tags: mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3, navigation, slide

I would like to change the default behavior of the standard Bootstrap 3 mobile navigation.

Instead of sliding downwards when clicking the toggle bar, I want the navigation to slide in from the right side.

I want to do so without injecting an extra navigation and without using the Jasny extension.

Has anyone done this successfully? Thank you very much for your help!!!